# How to be notified of an NSTask's terminationStatus after it exits without blocking?

Tags: swift, macos, grand-central-dispatch, nstask

**OS X Deployment Target: 10.11**

Given an [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/), that has an assigned *[qualityOfService](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/PrioritizeWorkAtTheTaskLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013929-CH35-SW1)* what is the recommended way to be notified when the task exits (i.e. [waitUntilExit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTask/waitUntilExit)) without blocking?

1. A [NSBackgroundActivityScheduler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/SchedulingBackgroundActivity.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013929-CH32-SW1).

   - Assigned the same quality of service as that of the NSTask.
   - Use [scheduleWithBlock](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSBackgroundActivitySchedulerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBackgroundActivityScheduler/scheduleWithBlock:) to waitUntilExit
   - Finally, dispatch_async to the main queue and post a notification.
2. A dispatch_queue_t, using [dispatch_get_global_queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1).

   - Switch on the quality of server of the NSTask to decide the QoS of the queue.
   - dispatch_async a block to waitUntilExit
   - Finally, dispatch_async to the main queue and post a notification.
3. Some other way?

Comment: NSTask has a terminationHandler property.

Comment: @rocky completely missed that. Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSTask's terminationHandler property.